# EEA Family Permit : Previous passports

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu, uk-visa, eu-spouses

My wife is about to apply for an EEA Family Permit to join me. 
She is missing one of her previous passports. Is it mandatory to submit all her previous passports?
what should we do if all previous passports are mandatory?

Please advice...

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

In theory, they shouldn't be asking about previous passports at all.  You should be fine just stating that one previous passport is missing, along with whatever information you have about the missing passport.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I (UK citizen) don't have most of my previous passports.  Obviously I am not going to be applying for an EEA Family Permit to move to the UK, but it does suggest that UK immigration authorities won't expect people to keep previous passports.